# Line breaks is not being followed on printing in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am getting this format from a json string:

```
ABCD\n EFG: HIJKL\n 
MNO: PQRST \n\n
UVW: XYZ
```

When I print it, the line breaks ("\n") is not inserted. I get the Json string like so:

```
val orReply = gson.fromJson<OrReply>(decryptedValue, OrReply::class.java)
printReceipt(orReply.ORData)
```

and use this reply as so:

```
private fun printReceipt(orString: String) {
   printOnPrinter(orString)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following function to process the line breaks and see if helps you in fixing the issue:

```
private fun processLineBreak(string: String) : String{
        return string.replace("\n",System.lineSeparator())
}
```